# Can I run TFS2010 on a development laptop alongside VS, SQL Server etc.?

Tags: windows-7, cvs

After about five years of Subversion use I need to get up to speed with MS Team Foundation Server which I will have to use from here on in. I'd like to install it on my laptop and build a couple of demo projects with it to get my head around how it works.

Is it possible to have it running on a dev (workstation) machine or does it insist on being deployed to a standalone server? Are there any caveats?

Thanks for reading.

ANSWER:

Always RTFM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578592.aspx  ;-)

Looks like everything except Sharepoint integration and reporting will work fine under Win7.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably install it on a workstation but I think there were some issues with installing it on Windows 7. A better solution might be to use a VM. Microsoft provide a [VM with everything already installed](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=509c3ba1-4efc-42b5-b6d8-0232b2cbb26e&displaylang=en) and ready to go.

This is a demo VM so the software will expire at some point, unless you get some licence keys from MSDN and activate all of the software.

Answer (score 0):

Always RTFM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578592.aspx

Looks like everything except Sharepoint integration and reporting will work fine under Win7.